# How to batch downstream operations in a serverless architecture?

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-functions, serverless

We have a multi-tenant solution, split over a number of internal services. These internal services (microservices if you wish...) are all built with Azure Functions (Node.js) and queues (Azure Service Bus and Azure Storage Queues).

For one of our services, the load distribution is very uneven. For any single tenant, we can see 400k operations in a matter of minutes, and then nothing for hours (or even days). For our internal service, this is not a problem - we put all operations on a Service Bus queue and process them one by one as quickly as possible. The problem is that every operation also needs to be passed to a third-party service after processing, and this service cannot handle the high-frequency processing of a microservice architecture. The third-party service is called over HTTP, and requires that multiple operations are batched in a single request (maximum 500 ops / request). The operations also need to be grouped by tenant when sent to the third-party service, so we cannot send operations from more than one tenant in a single request.

One way to solve this might be to temporarily store every processed operation in CosmosDB or Table Storage, and then have a separate Azure Function that continuously queries that storage for new operations, fetch them 500 at a time, and pass them along to the third-party service. This would probably work, but since we want to send operations downstream as quickly as possible (ideally within seconds, and not more than minutes), and we would have to query for every single tenant to check if there are new operations to send, there would be a lot of wasted cycles given the very uneven distribution of operations.

Another way *might* be to use Service Bus and create a topic for every tenant. We could then put all processed operations on the right topic, and then consume those messages in batches and pass them along to the third-party service. The upside of this is that we wouldn't have to continuously query for new operations. The downside is that we would have to have A LOT of topics, and topics don't *feel* like the right tool for the job - but I might be wrong.

Are there any better solutions to this problem?

Comment: I believe you would want to throttle the calls to the external service. Is that correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri Exactly, ideally I want to send them downstream to the external service, 500 at a time, but at the same time not wait too long in case the batch doesn't fill up.

Comment: Have you thought about sending output to another Service Bus Queue but the messages are sent with a random delay (using message enqueue time)?

Comment: @GauravMantri If I get you right, that would even out the distribution of messages somewhat, but it wouldn't help me batching those calls, or am I missing something? Rather than distributing them, what I ideally want to do is group them together in groups of 500 and pass them along as quickly as possible.